# How to effectively use the `-Filter` parameter on Active Directory cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

All too often I see the following type of code on this site, specific to the AD cmdlets:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | Where-Object { $_.EmailAddress -eq $email }
```

The problem is that you are returning every single user object in Active Directory, and then processing it a second time. How can we improve upon this, not only to reduce the time it takes to run the script, but to also take the unnecessary load off of Active Directory, and possibly the network?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> #### Note about Azure AD cmdlets
>
> This answer is crafted around the Active Directory cmdlets installed and available from `Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT)`. However, the Azure AD cmdlets make use of [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) (OData v4.0 specification) to run queries against Azure AD while the [RSAT cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10))<sup>[1]</sup> rely on an implementation of the PowerShell Expression Engine intended to replace LDAP filters.
>
> As such, the filter examples below will not work with Azure AD cmdlets without some modification to be compatible with the Microsoft Graph specification, specifically, its [filter syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter). However, the general practices mentioned here should still apply.
>
> <sup>[1] - This is the most recent version of this document I could find.</sup>

## What is so bad about `-Filter *`?

You are effectively selecting and returning every object that exists in AD, based on the cmdlet you are using (e.g. `Get-ADUser`, `Get-ADComputer`, `Get-ADGroup`, the generic `Get-ADObject`, etc.). This is an expensive thing to do, especially in larger AD environments. In large enough environments you will want to split up your queries in batches, even if you legitimately need to operate on every AD object of a given type. On top of this, your script will end up processing far more data than it needs to, increasing execution time and used processing time when it just isn't necessary.

The `-Filter` parameter can do more than just match on everything, which is effectively what 
`-Filter *` does. The `-Filter` string is very much like Powershell syntax (not quite, but most of the way there). You can use most of the same logical operators that Powershell supports, and they work much in the same way that Powershell operators do. This answer aims to clarify this and explain how to use this elusive parameter. These examples will use the `Get-ADUser` cmdlets but this also extends to the other `Get-ADObject` cmdlets which use filters as well.

---

## Syntax

The syntax for the `-Filter` string is `"PropertyName -comparisonoperator 'somevalue'"`, though you can string multiple conditions together with logical operators such as `-and` and `-or`. Note that there are no regex matching operators, so you will have to make do with `-like` and
`-notlike` globbing.

#### Comparison Operators

MS calls these `FilterOperators` but they are used in the same way as
PowerShell's comparison operators are (ignoring the fact that *technically* `-bor` and `-band` are arithmetic operators). These are used for comparing values:

> **Note:** AD attributes in **DistinguishedName** format will not have globbing applied when
> `-like` or `-notlike` are used, in other words you have to look for an exact match. If you need a DN to match any pattern, this cannot be performed with `-Filter` or
> `-LDAPFilter`. You will have to `-Filter` where you can, and perform additional processing with the `-like` or `-match` operators once your `Get-ADObject` cmdlet returns.

`-eq`, `-le`, `-ge`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-gt`, `-approx`, `-bor`, `-band`, `-recursivematch`, `-like`, `-notlike`

The only ones which are unique to the `-Filter` query syntax are `-approx` and
`-recursivematch`. [Don't worry about `-approx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57700052/584676), it is functionally equivalent to `-eq` in Active Directory.

Despite its name, `-recursivematch` is **not** a regex matching operator, it works like PowerShell's
`-contains` operator in that it will return `$true` if the collection contains the target value.

#### Logical Operators

MS calls these `JoinOperators` but they fill the same role as their PowerShell logical operator equivalent. These are used to join multiple conditions together in a single query:

`-and`, `-or`

Strangely enough, MS gives negation to a special operator type called `NotOperator`, which consists of a single operator:

`-not`

---

## Matching on a property

To use the example in the question, let's find a user matching an email address, but without piping to `Where-Object` (crazy right???):

```
$email = 'box@domain.tld'
Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '${email}'"
```

Done. `Get-ADUser` will return any accounts where the `EmailAddress` property equals whatever the `$email` variable is.

What if we want to find all user accounts that haven't been logged onto in the last 30 days? But a date string is more complex than an email! Who cares, still pretty simple!

```
# Get the date from 30 days ago

$notUsedSince = ( Get-Date ).AddDays( -30 )
Get-ADUser -Filter "LastLogonDate -lt '${notUsedSince}'"
```

This returns all users who have not logged on in the last 30 days.

---

## Getting users who are members of a group

If you want to get all `ADUsers` who are members of a certain group, we can make use of the
`-recursivematch` operator for this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "memberOf -recursivematch 'CN=test_group,CN=Users,DC=exampledomain,DC=net'"
```

`memberOf` is an `array` of **Distinguished Names**, `-recursivematch` returns true if the array on the lefthand side contains the value on the righthand side.

You can alternatively avoid the use of `Get-ADUser` at all in this scenario and use `Get-ADGroup` to retrieve the members from that:

```
( Get-ADGroup group_name -Properties Members ).Members
```

While the `Get-ADGroup` example above is shorter to type, filtering on `memberOf` with
`Get-ADUser` can be effective when you have multiple conditions and need to return users that are members of a group, but not necessarily need to return the group for local processing. It may be interactively inconvenient but it is a worthy technique in any automated process integrating with Active Directory and may become necessary in cases where you have extremely large groups.

One example is when enumerating `Domain Users` in a very large domain. You *might* want to rethink returning 32,000 users from `( Get-ADGroup ).Members` to then have to apply additional filtering.

> **Note:** Most users will actually have `Domain Users` set as their `PrimaryGroup`. This is the default and most times this doesn't need to be changed. However, you must use
> `-Filter` on `PrimaryGroup` instead as the `PrimaryGroup` is not stored under `MemberOf` for an `ADUser`. It is also a single value, not a collection, so use `-eq`:
>
> ```
> Get-ADUser -Filter "PrimaryGroup -eq 'PRIMARY_GROUP_DN'"
> ```

---

## What if the query term contains a quote?

Quotes in the query term will throw a wrench in your query in most cases. Consider the example of searching for users with `O'Niel` in the name. This can break either the query or your script logic depending on the quoting technique used:

```
# Our heroic search term
$term = "O'Niel"

# Dragons abound (results in a query parsing error)
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*${term}*'"

# Your princess is in another castle ($term is not expanded
# and the literal string ${term} is instead searched for) 
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "*${term}*"'
```

In this case you will have to use double-quoted strings in both places, but fortunately the escape-hell isn't too bad. Using the same value for `$term` as before:

```
# Your quest is over (this works as intended and returns users named O'Niel)
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like ""*${term}*"""

# Backticks are ugly but this also works
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like `"*${term}*`""
```

> **Note:** If your query looks for a field value which contains *both* single and double quotes, I'm not sure how to facilitate this with one command when using the `-Filter` parameter. However, `-LDAPFilter` should be able to facilitate this, as parentheses `()`, not quotes, are used for the internal query bounds. See the `Filter Examples` in [about_ActiveDirectory_Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)) and the `LDAP Filters` section of [this AD Escape Characters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx#LDAP_Filters) post for more information, as `-LDAPFilter` is beyond the scope of this answer.

---

## Matching on multiple properties

Matching on multiple properties is not much different, but it's best to wrap each condition in parentheses `()`. Here's an example, let's find non-domain admin accounts (assuming we know this by the username nomenclature `*-da`) that don't have an email address associated with them.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "(samaccountname -notlike '*-da') -and (EmailAddress -notlike '*')"
```

This one is a little trickier, because we can't pass in an empty value for the right side of a condition in the `-Filter`, as in the case for `EmailAddress`. But '*' matches any non-empty value, so we can leverage that behavior with the `-notlike` comparison operator to find empty values for `EmailAddress`. To break down the filter, make sure that any accounts ending in `-da` aren't matched by the filter, *and then* also only match accounts that do not have an `EmailAddress` value.

---

## Things to avoid

1. [Don't try to use a `{ ScriptBlock }` for your filter parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/584676). Yes, we are all more comfortable with writing a `ScriptBlock` than worrying about building a `string` and making sure it's escaped properly. There is definitely an attraction to using them. I've seen so many answers using a `ScriptBlock` as a `-Filter` argument, or people having problems (myself included) trying to do something like this, and SURPRISE!!! Nothing gets returned:

   ```
   Import-Csv C:\userInfoWithEmails.csv | Foreach-Object {
     Get-ADUser -Filter { EmailAddress -eq $_.Email }
   }
   ```

   `-Filter` doesn't support `ScriptBlocks`, but they **Kind of Work Sometimes™** because while they get rendered as a literal string, the PowerShell Expression Engine used by `-Filter` is capable of rendering your variables before running the query. Because of this, they will technically work if you use simple variable expansion like `$_` or `$emailAddress`, but it will eventually cause you a headache, especially if you try to access an object property (like above) because it simply won't work.

   In addition, you get largely undocumented (or difficult to locate info) behavior for how these variables are expanded, because they are not always `ToString'd` [like you would expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69107959/584676). Figuring it out becomes a trial-and-error affair. Some attributes are admittedly easier to obtain this way, but using techniques you don't understand and which have little documentation is a risky move when programming. Because of this, I don't relying on the cmdlet-internal variable expansion that occurs whether you use a literal string or a `ScriptBlock` with the AD cmdlets.

   Use a string filter every time, and if you need to use a variable value or object property as a portion of the filter, use [Variable Substitution](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-01-13-powershell-variable-substitution-in-strings/#variable-substitution) or [Command Substitution](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-01-13-powershell-variable-substitution-in-strings/#command-substitution).
2. You do not need to specify additional `-Properties` if you only care about a property to filter on it. The AD cmdlets can evaluate all properties within the `-Filter` parameter without needing to pass them down the pipeline.
3. And while I'm at it, don't ever use `-Properties *`, excepting maybe if you are inspecting all properties on a returned object for some reason, such as during script development, or interactively you're not quite sure what you're looking for (note that [not all attributes are returned by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51501467/584676)).
   Only specify the properties you need to process after the AD object has been returned. There is a reason for this - some properties are particularly expensive to get the values for. Best practice is to only forward the properties you need to process down the pipeline.
4. You cannot use the `-Filter` parameter to filter on [Constructed Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/a3aff238-5f0e-4eec-8598-0a59c30ecd56) using either
   `-Filter` or `-LDAPFilter`. This is because constructed attributes are, by definition, computed  (or "constructed") on the fly, and are not actually stored values within Active Directory. I imagine it's because many Computed Attributes are expensive to compute, which would have to be performed on every relevant `ADObject` to filter on it from the AD side.

   If you need to filter on Constructed Attributes, you will need to first return a set of `ADObjects`, specifying the `Computed Attribute` with `-Properties`, then further filter with `Where-Object` or some other technique.
5. Wildcards `*` do not work for fields that return a `DistinguishedName` type, such as `DistinguishedName`, `manager`, `PrimaryGroup`, etc. In addition, `DistinguishedNames` carry their [own set of escaping rules](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx#Active_Directory).
6. Some AD attributes are returned as a proper `DateTime` for easier processing in PowerShell, but the basic time comparison exemplified above requires the underlying `ADAttribute` to be defined as the `Interval` type. Some time-based properties, such as `whenCreated` are defined as **Generalized-Time strings**, which are UTC timezone and formatted as `yyyMMddHHmmss.Z`. Additionally, some properties like
   `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` are in **file-time format** (and is returned as such with the AD cmdlets).

   - Convert a target `DateTime` for filtering to the **Generalized-Time string** format like so:

     ```
     ( Get-Date ).ToUniversalTime().ToString('yyyMMddHHmmss.z').
     ```

     Note that this string is not directly convertible back to a `DateTime`.
   - Convert a returned **file-time** to a `DateTime` like so (using the aforementioned property as an example):

     ```
     [DateTime]::FromFileTime($adUser.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed')
     ```

---

## In summarium

These techniques using the `-Filter` parameter with the AD cmdlets will save you costly processing time when iterating over large AD environments, and should improve the performance of your Powershell AD operations. I hope this helps explain some of the elusive behaviors of the AD cmdlets' `-Filter` parameter.

## Additional Resources

As it is a good idea to understand the AD attributes you are working with, below are some Microsoft resources to help you identify and understand how different attributes are defined and function within the AD schema, as well as learn more about the `-Filter` syntax:

- [OpenSpecs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-ada3/ada870e9-f8d3-4e3b-bc80-b3a888f05204)
- [AD Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-whencreated)
- [about_ActiveDirectory_Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10))

  - While outdated, this document help is still accurate. [Due to a bug](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-powershell-docs/issues/1333#issuecomment-756700718) it has not been updated since 2013. [Until this bug is fixed](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-powershell-docs/issues/2247) and the documentation has been updated, the above link will have to suffice.

Comment: This has just made my life SO.MUCH.EASIER !!!

Comment: For more information on PowerShell's Operators see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3 .