# Why am I getting no output when I try to search for a deleted user in Active Directory through PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to search Active Directory for deleted users with PowerShell, but am unable to return any results even though I have used the `-IncludeDeletedObjects` parameter. Here is the command that I used:

```
get-adobject -filter{Name -like "$user"} -includedeletedobjects -properties *
```

Comment: This is going to be pretty tough for us to troubleshoot from outside your environment. I don't see anything glaringly wrong with that command. Are you using a user name that does exist? What does $user hold?

Comment: Is the activedirectory recycle bin enabled? If you just use `-Filter *` do you get any objects back?

Comment: Thanks guys for the response everything is working ok now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that worked for me is the command below will list all the users that were deleted from the Active Directory if your AD recycle bin is enabled and if you have sufficient privileges on Active Directory

```
Get-AdObject -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "user" -and IsDeleted -eq $True' -IncludeDeletedObjects -Properties * | Ft Name,IsDeleted,WhenCreated
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the [AD Recycle Bin](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793473.aspx) enabled, you won't be able to find deleted objects.

If `$user` is expected to an exact match, you should also be using the `-eq` operator, not `-like`. If you want a fuzzy match, `-like` is correct but you should surround `$user` with `*` like so: `*${user}*`.

If `$user` is supposed to be the logon name, and not the friendly name of the user, then `Name` isn't the correct property to filter on, you will want to check against `SamAccountName`, not `Name`:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$user'"
```

---

If you are *only* interested in user objects, and not other AD object types, consider using
`Get-ADUser` in lieu of `Get-ADObject`. The syntax for what you specified above is the same, but will guarantee you only get `ADUser` objects, not `ADComputer`, `ADGroup`, etc.

---

Also, you should avoid using `-Properties *` and `-Filter { ScriptBlock }` arguments when using the AD cmdlets. Only use the Properties you need to process later, and use a string based filter like so:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter "Name -like '*$user*'"
```

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218670/how-to-effectively-use-the-filter-parameter-on-active-directory-cmdlets/51218671#51218671) for best practices when using the `-Filter` parameter with AD cmdlets (also explains why not to use `-Properties *`), and [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/584676) for more details on why you should not use `ScriptBlock` parameters for AD filters.

Answer (score 0):

Elevate your script or powershell console. That resolved the issue for me.