# How does the Active Directory "-approx" filter operator work?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

While going over the AD Cmdlet `-Filter` operators earlier today, I came across one I've not seen before: `-approx`. I can find this operator mentioned on several blogs, and in some TechNet articles, but nothing I find explains what this operator is used for. I also cannot find any examples of its use beyond its definition of use as "approxiomately equal to", or `~=`. The only time I've used the `~=` operator when programming is in Ruby, which does a regular expression match, but regex matching doesn't seem to be how it's used in this case. The only way I've gotten it to return *anything* is if I provide the exact value of the property I'm filtering on like in this example:

```
 Get-AdUser -Filter "samaccountname -approx 'myexactsamaccountname'"
```

What is the proper usage of this operator, and what examples might there be of using it as an Active Directory administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is probably not as exciting as you'd hoped, but...*

From the [Active Directory Technical Specification §3.1.1.3.1.3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/0bb88bda-ed8d-4af7-9f7b-813291772990):

> Active Directory supports the `approxMatch` filter clause of [RFC2251] section 4.5.1. However, **it is implemented identically to** `equalityMatch`; for example, the filter is true if the values are equal. No approximation is performed. Filter clauses of the form `"(X=Y)"` and `"(X~=Y)"` can be freely substituted for each other.

<sup>(emphasis added)</sup>

So, it is simply there because RFC2251 defines (and RFC4511 describes) `approxMath` as part of the supported set of operators in LDAPv3 - and Microsoft wanted to be able to claim that the LDAP server implementation in Active Directory conforms to both LDAPv2 and LDAPv3 - so they added it without changing its behavior (the implementation details of which the relevant RFCs never prescribe anyways). This is in line with the description [found in RFC4511](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.5.1.7.6):

> An `approxMatch` filter is TRUE when there is a value of the
> attribute    type or subtype for which some locally-defined
> approximate matching    algorithm (e.g., spelling variations, phonetic
> match, etc.) returns    TRUE.  If a value matches for equality, it
> also satisfies an    approximate match.  If approximate matching is
> not supported for the    attribute, this filter item should be treated
> as an `equalityMatch`.

The original intent was likely to allow common or local approximations, or possibly to allow for equivalence-matching across multiple alphabets, ie. a search for:

```
(givenName~=thorbjorn)
```

Would return anyone with the given name Torbjorn, Þórrbjorn, or Thorbjørn

Comment: You're right, that is totally lame. Glad to know I've not been missing out on something though