# Discovery of OS version not Windows 10 1809 across the network Powershell command

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to check which devices in our network,
Which does not have the OS version 1809 Windows 10 and I need to do a scan to determine those devices pulling data from AD.

```
  Try{$Domain = $(get-addomain).dnsroot}
  Catch{$Domain = ""}

  $Log = "C:\Temp\Audit\$Domain OS Compliance $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"

  $Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Enabled -eq $True} -Property * | 
  Select Enabled,Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion

  foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
  {
   #properties
   $Version = $Computer.OperatingSystemVersion
   $Enabled = $Computer.Enabled
   $Name = $Computer.Name
   $OS = $Computer.OperatingSystem
  }

  #Windows10 Build 1908 check
  If($OS -like "Windows 10*")
  {
      $Type = "Computer"
      $CountComputers++
      $Build = "1908"


   $obj = New-Object PSobject
   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Enabled" -Value $Enabled
   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $Computer.Name
   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Operating System" -Value 
       $Computer.OperatingSystem
   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Version" -Value $Version
   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Build" -Value $Build
  }

  $OutData = $OutData | sort -Property "Type","Name"
  $OutData | Export-CSV $Log -notype -Encoding UTF8
  write-host "Log Export Complete to $Log" -foregroundcolor yellow
```

I seem to be doing something wrong calling out the query I am not that well versed with Powershell anyone can share me or give me any inputs so i can formulate my own code would help out

Comment: As an aside: It's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a computer with RSAT tools installed (or from a DC) you can run the following using an account that can access all PCs/servers in the domain:

```
$computers = ( Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties DNSHostName ).DNSHostName
$results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers {
  switch ( [System.Environment]::OsVersion.Version.Major ) {
    10 {
      [PSCustomObject]@{ AtLeast1809 = [System.Environment]::OsVersion.Version.Build -ge 18362 }
      break
    }
    default {
      [PSCustomObject]@{ AtLeast1809 = $False }
    }
  }
}

$results | Where-Object { -Not $_.AtLeast1809 } | Select-Object PSComputerName, AtLeast1809
```

This code looks at the current major version, if it's not 10, we automatically return `$false`. If it's Windows 10, we check the build version. Once `Invoke-Command` runs on all computers in the domain, we then output from the `$results` collection for any computers where the version is not at least Windows 10 1809, then select the `PSComputerName` property (an automatic property added when using `Invoke-Command` to note which computer the result came from) and the `AtLeast1809` property which we returned from the remote computer.

Note that you may not want to run this against every single computer/server in your domain at once. You may want to [adjust the filter parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218670/how-to-effectively-use-the-filter-parameter-on-active-directory-cmdlets/51218671#51218671) to select only computers you want in batches.

[Here is the lookup table for Windows 10 versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Rings). 1809 is build 18362.