# Count AD group members with certain properties

Tags: powershell, directory, office365

I need a PowerShell script to count the members of an AD group that have the extensionAttribute4 property equal to o365_facstaff.

I’ve been using the following script to count all members of the group but I specifically need just the ones with the property:

```
$ADInfo = Get-AdGroup -Identity ‘<group name>’ -Properties Members 
$ADInfo.Members.Count
```

Comment: `$ADInfo.Members |Where-Object {(Get-ADUser $_ -Properties extensionAttribute4).extensionAttribute4 -eq 'o365_facstaff'} |Measure-Object`

Answer (score 0):

We can get this information from AD with a single `-Filter` query on `Get-ADUser`:

```
# We'll need the group DN instead of the group name
# Here's an example
$groupDn = 'CN=test_group,CN=Users,DC=bender,DC=net'

# Get all ADUsers member of the target group with the specific 
$groupMembers = Get-ADUser -Filter "(memberOf -RecursiveMatch '$groupDn') -and (extensionAttribute4 -eq 'o365_facstaff')"

# Check the Count property like you would with any array
$groupMembers.Count
```

Alternatively, as also mentioned in the comments, you can get the group members off of the `ADGroup` and further filter, though this results in additional unnecessary local processing. This can become problematic with very large groups, especially if your ADDS infrastructure runs closer to the minimum system requirements:

```
# Using $ADInfo from your code sample
$membersWithfacstaff = $ADInfo.Members | Where-Object {
  ( Get-ADUser $_ -Properties extensionAttribute4 ).extensionAttribute4 -eq 'o365_facstaff'
}

# Use the Count property
$facstaff.Count
```

As also mentioned in the comments, `Measure-Command` will give you the count too but is a bit redundant here, considering you'd have to reference the `Count` property anyways if you want to use it programmatically.

---

See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51218671/584676) for more information on effectively using the `-Filter` parameter on the RSAT AD cmdlets.