# powershell to get exact date for passwordlastset

Tags: powershell, date

I'm working on scripts which send emails to users 14, 10, 7, 3 days before password expiring.
Password expires in 60 days.

If I set like below it works for accounts with 3 and less days to expiring. I don't want accounts with 2 days, 1 day, etc.

```
$ExpiringUsers = $AdUsers | where PasswordLastSet -lt (get-date).AddDays(-57)
```

If I set like below it doesn't work at all

```
$ExpiringUsers = $AdUsers | where PasswordLastSet -eq (get-date).AddDays(-57)
```

How to set equal 3 days not more not less.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi here you can read more https://gist.github.com/talzcloning/9884c37d2361b04a4040129a1a8488a5

Comment: Hi, its exactly what I did yesterday. This script is easy to understand and works like a charm. It took many years to give it such form :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define and filter by a time range, for example, *set equal 3 days not more not less* would be like this:

```sh
$start = [datetime].AddDays(-3)   # => April 2 at 12:00 AM
$finish = [datetime].AddDays(-2)  # => April 3 at 12:00 AM

# Note `-lt $finish` instead of `-le $finish`
$AdUsers | Where-Object { $_.PasswordLastSet -ge $start -and $_.PasswordLastSet -lt $finish }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` for checking how long until the account credential expires:

```
$serviceAccounts = 
  'acct1@domain.tld',
  'acct2@domain.tld

$daysLeft = 20
$expiringAccounts = ( $serviceAccounts | Foreach-Object {
  Get-AdUser -Filter "(UserPrincipalName -eq '$_' -Or sAMAccountName -eq '$_' ) -And ( PasswordNeverExpires -eq 'false' )" -Properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed |
  Where-Object { ( New-TimeSpan -Start $currentDate -End ( [DateTime]::FromFileTime( $_.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed' ) ) ).Days -le $daysLeft }
} )
```

- As written, this code will gather the accounts expiring within 20 days. Adjust `$daysLeft` to control the remaining threshold until expiry.
- Note that `[DateTime]::FromFileTime` is required to transpose the value of
  `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` from the file-time format it is stored in AD as to a workable `DateTime` object.
- You can define the account as a `sAMAccountName` or in `Universal Principal Name (UPN)` format.
- This also exemplifies using AD filters in order to have AD return only the objects you need for this query, minimizing the local processing performed with `Where-Object`.

  - The notable exception is `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed`; because it is a [Constructed Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/a3aff238-5f0e-4eec-8598-0a59c30ecd56) within Active Directory, neither AD filters or LDAP filters can evaluate it and so this must be done via additional local processing.
  - Here is [an answer I have also written](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51218671/584676) which goes into deeper detail on using the AD filter syntax.

---

#### What is wrong with `PasswordLastSet` for checking credential expiration if you know the account's lifecycle?

The problem with checking `PasswordLastSet` is that, while it works, if the threshold until expiry changes on the Active Directory side, your script will need to be updated or it will incorrectly identify accounts whose credential is set to expire soon. It also becomes more difficult to track which accounts are beholden to different lifecycles in environments where not all accounts are beholden to the same security policies.